# SpriteKit Terminating App due NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, sprite-kit

My App is giving the following output :

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Attemped to add nil node', reason: 'Attemped to add nil node to parent: <SKScene> name:'(null)' frame:{{0, 0}, {320, 568}}'
*** First throw call stack:
(
0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7b495 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001017da99e objc_exception_throw + 43
2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a7b2ad +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
3   SpriteKit                           0x0000000101271622 -[SKNode addChild:] + 161
4   Jump'n'Run Game                     0x00000001000057cb -[MyScene BodenHindernisse] + 9067
5   SpriteKit                           0x00000001012905e0 -[SKPerformSelector updateWithTarget:forTime:] + 85
6   SpriteKit                           0x000000010124f68a _ZN11SKCSequence27cpp_updateWithTargetForTimeEP9SKCSprited + 66
7   SpriteKit                           0x000000010124ac32 _ZN9SKCRepeat27cpp_updateWithTargetForTimeEP9SKCSprited + 40
8   SpriteKit                           0x000000010128968b _ZN9SKCSprite6updateEd + 235
9   SpriteKit                           0x0000000101255a6f -[SKScene _update:] + 101
10  SpriteKit                           0x00000001012688c2 -[SKView(Private) _update:] + 223
11  SpriteKit                           0x00000001012668a7 -[SKView renderCallback:] + 869
12  SpriteKit                           0x0000000101267b7d -[SKView layoutSubviews] + 364
13  UIKit                               0x00000001002bc993 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 354
14  QuartzCore                          0x00000001040f5802 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 151
15  QuartzCore                          0x00000001040ea369 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 363
16  QuartzCore                          0x00000001040f5736 -[CALayer layoutIfNeeded] + 162
17  UIKit                               0x0000000100362a22 -[UIViewController window:setupWithInterfaceOrientation:] + 264
18  UIKit                               0x0000000100299cad -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:isRotating:] + 4360
19  UIKit                               0x0000000100298b9f -[UIWindow _setRotatableClient:toOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 36
20  UIKit                               0x0000000100298aef -[UIWindow _setRotatableViewOrientation:updateStatusBar:duration:force:] + 101
21  UIKit                               0x0000000100297dfe -[UIWindow _updateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:force:] + 377
22  UIKit                               0x000000010035670a -[UIViewController _tryBecomeRootViewControllerInWindow:] + 147
23  UIKit                               0x0000000100292b1b -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 490
24  UIKit                               0x0000000100292c70 -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
25  UIKit                               0x000000010029bffa -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 51
26  UIKit                               0x0000000100257c98 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1788
27  UIKit                               0x000000010025ba0c -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 660
28  UIKit                               0x000000010026cd4c -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 3189
29  UIKit                               0x000000010026d216 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 79
30  UIKit                               0x000000010025d086 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 578
31  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103c8471a _PurpleEventCallback + 762
32  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000103c841e1 PurpleEventCallback + 35
33  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019fd679 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
34  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001019fd44e __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 478
35  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a26903 __CFRunLoopRun + 1939
36  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101a25d83 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
37  UIKit                               0x000000010025b2e1 -[UIApplication _run] + 609
38  UIKit                               0x000000010025ce33 UIApplicationMain + 1010
39  Jump'n'Run Game                     0x00000001000085b3 main + 115
40  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001021125c9 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

So basically, my app is trying to spawn obstacles in a row forever, but there seems to be an error in my code. I used the SpriteNode 'Enemy' as a 'head'Subclass, so that I got 1 Enemy, and the cases define the texture of the Enemy. Also shortened, because the problem seems to be in the spawn definition.

```
     -(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
     .....
     SKAction * Spawn = [SKAction performSelector:@selector(BodenHindernisse) onTarget:self];
        SKAction * Delay = [SKAction waitForDuration:2];
        SKAction * SpawnThenDelay = [SKAction sequence:@[Spawn, Delay]];
        SKAction * SpawnThenDelayForever = [SKAction repeatActionForever:SpawnThenDelay];
        [self runAction:SpawnThenDelayForever];
     ....
     }


    -(void)BodenHindernisse {

    switch (arc4random_uniform(4)){

    case 0:
        if(Day){
            Feind = Steine;

            Steine = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Stein.png"];
            Steine.size = CGSizeMake(50, 55);
            Steine.zPosition = 2;

            Steine.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:16];
            Steine.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
            Steine.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
            Steine.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
            Steine.physicsBody.restitution = 0;

            Steine.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = HindernissCategory;
            Steine.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;
            Steine.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;

            Feind.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, Boden.position.y + 69);
        }

        if(Night){
            Feind = Zombie;

            Zombie = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Zombie.png"];
            Zombie.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
            Zombie.zPosition = 2;

            Zombie.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(30, 50)];
            Zombie.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
            Zombie.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
            Zombie.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
            Zombie.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
            Zombie.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

            Zombie.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = HindernissCategory;
            Zombie.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;
            Zombie.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;

            Feind.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, Boden.position.y + 75);
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if(Day){
        Feind = MenschSchwert;

        SKTexture * MenschSTexture1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"MenschSchwert1"];
        MenschSTexture1.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;
        SKTexture * MenschSTexture2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"MenschSchwert2"];
        MenschSTexture2.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringNearest;

        SKAction * Run = [SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction animateWithTextures:@[MenschSTexture1, MenschSTexture2] timePerFrame:0.25]];

        MenschSchwert = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:MenschSTexture1];
        MenschSchwert.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
        MenschSchwert.zPosition = 2;

        MenschSchwert.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 50)];
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

        [MenschSchwert runAction:Run];

        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = HindernissCategory;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;
        MenschSchwert.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = BodenCategory | MenschCategory;

        Feind.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, Boden.position.y + 75);
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        Feind = Block;

        Block = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Block.png"];
        Block.size = CGSizeMake(40, 35);
        Block.zPosition = 2;

        Block.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(30, 35)];
        Block.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        Block.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        Block.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        Block.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
        Block.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

        Block.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = LuftHindernissCategory;
        Block.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = MenschCategory;
        Block.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = MenschCategory;

        Feind.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, Boden.position.y + 110);
        break;
    case 3:
        Feind = Stachel;

        Stachel = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Stachel.png"];
        Stachel.size = CGSizeMake(60, 60);
        Stachel.zPosition = 2;

        Stachel.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:CGSizeMake(40, 45)];
        Stachel.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
        Stachel.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO;
        Stachel.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
        Stachel.physicsBody.restitution = 0;
        Stachel.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

        Stachel.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = LuftHindernissCategory;
        Stachel.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = MenschCategory;
        Stachel.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = MenschCategory;

        Feind.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width * 1.25, Boden.position.y + 100);
        break;
    default:
        break;

}

SKAction * actionMove = [SKAction moveToX:-100 duration:5];
SKAction * actionMoveDone = [SKAction removeFromParent];

[Feind runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[actionMove,actionMoveDone]]]];

[self addChild:Feind];
```

}

Comment: That code is terribly inefficient. Every time you run BodenHindernisse you create one instance of each type (Zombie, Block, Stachel, etc.) only to add just one of them (the one assigned to the Enemy variable). The remaining nodes are initialized, set up and then discarded. That will make it a lot harder to debug as well. You should first decide which type of object to create, then only create and add that specific type.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But thats exactly what I want, a random 'Enemy'. Its like an endless game. Setting the Object in an exactly row would destroy the game flow.

Comment: I don't think you got the point. In short, consider Steine: you create a sprite and assign it to Steine. You set up the Steine physics body. In all cases where arc4random_umiform does not return 0 Steine is never added as child and thus discarded at the end of the method. In effect the entire Steine code is only necessary if and only if arc4random returns 0. In all other cases it's just extra work that is ignored. You should setup your nodes and physics bodies **inside** the switch case, not before and after!

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now. I changed it, and now its crashing at the beginning, with the 'Attemped to add nil node' output.And the Breakout exception still don't give the wrong code. Thank you for taking your time to answer me.

Comment: `BodenHindernisse` method is really too big. Good practice is to break such big methods to several pieces (methods) to avoid potential bugs.

Comment: But the Spritenodes should be all together and called by the SpawnThenDelayForever action. If I would split them into several methods, which I tried, they would spawn not as I like. Still cant resolve the issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As error description states, you are trying to add an `SKNode`, which already has a parent. Make sure that `parent` is `nil` before adding.

Add [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) to locate the exact line, where the error occurs.

PS: Why did you omit a necessary parts of your code? It's always better to paste more code, than less.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried it, but it still crashes. I added more information.